# Bib latex - How to remove period between author and year

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am struggling finding a way to adapt the APA standard. I would like to remove the period after the author part. The bibliography should look like this:

> Author XYZ (2017). *Title.* Abgerufen am 15.11.2017 von https://url.xy

However, with APA it adds a period after the author:

> Author XYZ. (2017). *Title.* Abgerufen am 15.11.2017 von https://url.xy

I tried `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\space}` but it just removes the period after the year.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
   retrieved = {Abgerufen am},
   from = {von},
   nodate = {{}ohne Datum},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\sample.bib}
   @online{onlinekoerperschaft,
           author = {{Author XYZ}},
           title = "Title",
           url = {https://url.xy},
           urldate = "2017-11-15"
   }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you alter the code of `biblatex-apa` in any way, your document is likely not APA compliant any more. If you didn't want to write an APA-compliant document in the first place, you should consider not using `biblatex-apa`, but one of the standard styles instead. If you are writing a document in neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung (post-1995, say) you should be using `ngerman` instead of `german`. Your MWE causes errors because you are missing `\NewBibliographyString{from}
\NewBibliographyString{retrieved}` before the `\DefineBibliographyStrings`.

Comment: thanks for this input! I indeed need an APA-compliant document but our university added some extras to it. 95% is APA, the rest I need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update for `biblatex-apa` v9.0+

Please keep in mind that the period is mandated by APA style, cf. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/report-government-agency-references.

For `biblatex-apa` v9 and above, which implement 7th edition APA style, we can redefine the `author/editor` bibmacro to use `nameyeardelim`, which we can then customise as in the standard styles.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib,biblist]{nonameyeardelim}{nameyeardelim}
\renewbibmacro*{author/editor}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{author}\AND\ifnameundef{groupauthor}}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
      {\usebibmacro{title}%
       % need to clear all title fields so we don't get them again later
       \clearfield{title}%
       \clearfield{subtitle}%
       \clearfield{titleaddon}%
       \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}\newblock}
      {\usebibmacro{editorinauthpos}%
       \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}\newblock}}
    {\usebibmacro{author}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}\newblock}%
  %
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{nci,
  author      = {{National Cancer Institute}},
  year        = {2019},
  title       = {Taking Time},
  subtitle    = {Support for People With Cancer},
  type        = {NIH Publication},
  number      = {18-2059},
  institution = {U.S. Department of Health and Human Services,
                 National Institutes of Health},
  url         = {https://www.cancer.gov/publications/patient-education/takingtime.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,nci}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: National Cancer Institute (2019). Taking time: Support for people with cancer (NIH Publication No. 18-2059). U.S. Department of Health and Human Services, National Institutes of Health. https://www.cancer.gov/publications/patient-education/takingtime.pdf]

See also [Adjustments to bibliography / no comma between author and year / no italic font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553151/35864) and https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/117.

---

### Old answer

You will need to slightly alter two `biblatex-apa` macros.

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifnameundef{author}
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{nameaddon}%
     \ifnameundef{with}
       {}
       {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
        \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
        \setunit*{\addspace}}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}}

\renewbibmacro*{editorinauthpos}{%
    \global\booltrue{bbx:editorinauthpos}%
    \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}%
       % need to clear editor so we don't get an "In" clause later
       % But we also need to set a flag to say we did this so we
       % don't lose sight of the fact we once had an editor for
       % various year placement tests
       \clearname{editor}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}%
       \setunit{\adddot\addspace}}}
```

The only change is before the calls to `\usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}`. In the `author` macro a `\newunit` was replaced by `\setunit{\addspace}`; in the `editorinauthpos` macro it was `\setunit{\adddot\addspace}`.

This solution assumes the current `biblatex-apa` version 7.5. If you are running an older version, please consider updating (remember to update `biblatex` to 3.8a and Biber to 2.8 with it). If that is not at all possible, replace `labelyear+extradate` with `labelyear+extrayear` inn the above macros, that should make the code run also with less recent versions of the package.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. It worked with `labelyear+extrayear`. I am using share latex. Don't know what version of `bib latex`.