# Adjustments to bibliography / no comma between author and year / no italic font

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am actually quite happy with the apa style but I need some help to achieve the following two adjustments:

[image]

I do not want a comma between the author's name and the year.
I don't want italic font at all. It appears for the title of books and for the name of the Journal for articles.

This is my current set up

```
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\space}
```

```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\printbibliography
```

Comment: The `biblatex-apa` style isn't really designed to be modified because it implements the exact APA styel; you might be better of adapting the `authoryear` style. But the comma is due to your redefinition of `newunitpunct`, so you need to explain what you thought you were doing when you added that. You can make titles italic using `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}`.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\isdot}` to remove the italics from titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alan Munn says in the comments: `biblatex-apa` is supposed to implement APA style as closely as possible with `biblatex`. It was not designed with (easy) customisability in mind.

Case in point: Usually you could get rid of the comma between name and year as easily as saying `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}`. But `biblatex-apa` doesn't use this delimiter and uses `\newunit\newblock` instead, so we need to make it use `namyeardelim` before we can use it to change the comma.

You can get rid of the italics by redefining the `...title` field formats. See for some background [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{author/editor}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{author}\AND\ifnameundef{groupauthor}}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
      {\usebibmacro{title}%
        % need to clear all title fields so we don't get them again later
        \clearfield{title}%
       \clearfield{subtitle}%
       \clearfield{titleaddon}}
      {\usebibmacro{editorinauthpos}}}
    {\usebibmacro{author}}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}
\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{origtitle}{\bbx@colon@search\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}\isdot}
\makeatother
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,cicero,worman,westfahl:space,gaonkar:in}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It took me a while but it worked out fine

Comment: Re `nameyeardelim` in `biblatex-apa` see https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/117.